# "echo -e" when called directly and when called via a shell-script

Tags: shell, echo

I've noticed `echo` behaves slightly differently when called directly

`root$echo "line1\nline2"`

and when called via a script:

```
#! /bin/sh

echo "line1\nline2"

[...]
```

The first case would print:

```
line1\nline2
```

, while the latter would print

```
line1
line2
```

So `echo` is always assumed to have flag `-e` when used in a script?

Comment: I'm not seeing any such behavior. Do you have some weird aliases set up or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your script has a shebang line of `#! /bin/sh`, while your interactive shell is probably Bash.    If you want Bash behavior, change the script to `#! /bin/bash` instead.

The two programs `sh` and `bash` are *different* shells.  Even on systems where `/bin/sh` and `/bin/bash` are the same program, it behaves differently depending on which command you use to invoke it.  (Though `echo` doesn't act like it has `-e` turned on by default in Bash's `sh` mode, so you're probably on a system whose `sh` is really `dash`.)

If you type `sh` at your prompt, you'll find that `echo` behaves the same way as in your script. But `sh` is not a very friendly shell for interactive use.

If you're trying to write maximally portable shell scripts, you should stick to vanilla `sh` syntax, but if you aren't writing for distribution far and wide, you can use Bash scripts - just make sure to tell the system that they are, in fact, Bash scripts, by putting `bash` in the shebang line.

The `echo` command is probably the most notoriously inconsistent command across shells, by the way.  So if you are going for portability, you're better off avoiding it entirely for anything other than straight up, no-options, no-escapes, always-a-newline output.  One pretty portable option is [printf](http://linux.die.net/man/1/printf).