# How to split in GNU makefile list of files into separate lines

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, freebsd, solaris-10

I have a variable containing list of files separated with string `_NEWLINE_`. I need to output that variable into a file so that each file is in a separate line. The trick is that it needs to works on FreeBSD and Solaris.

This is what I am trying now:

```
echo "lib/alarms-1.2/priv/snmp_conf/agent.conf: lib/alarms/priv/snmp_conf/agent.conf_NEWLINE_lib/alarms-1.2/priv/snmp_conf/agent.conf.src: lib/alarms/priv/snmp_conf/agent.conf.src_NEWLINE_lib/alarms-1.2/priv/snmp_conf/community.conf: lib/alarms/priv/snmp_conf/community.conf" | sed 's|_NEWLINE_|\'$'\n|g'
```

This works on FreeBSD and in shell on Solaris. But when run in GNUmakefile on Solaris I am getting this (notice $ at the end of each line):

```
lib/alarms-1.2/priv/snmp_conf/agent.conf: lib/alarms/priv/snmp_conf/agent.conf$
lib/alarms-1.2/priv/snmp_conf/agent.conf.src: lib/alarms/priv/snmp_conf/agent.conf.src$
lib/alarms-1.2/priv/snmp_conf/community.conf: lib/alarms/priv/snmp_conf/community.conf$
```

If I remove `\'$'` from sed then it works on Solaris but doesn't on FreeBSD. Maybe there is a way of telling which version to use depending on which system the makefile is executed?

**EDIT:**
Thanks to the solution proposed by **bobbogo** I created an exemplary makefile that provides the desired outcome and seems to be working on both FreeBSD and Solaris:

```
one-line := lib/alarms-1.2/priv/snmp_conf/agent.conf: lib/alarms/priv/snmp_conf/agent.conf_NEWLINE_lib/alarms-1.2/\
priv/snmp_conf/agent.conf.src: lib/alarms/priv/snmp_conf/agent.conf.src_NEWLINE_lib/alarms-1.2/priv/snmp_conf/comm\
unity.conf: lib/alarms/priv/snmp_conf/community.conf

many-lines := { echo '$(subst _NEWLINE_,' && echo ',${one-line})'; }

.PHONY: all
all:
  $(shell $(many-lines) > test.txt)
```

Comment: Having read the accepted answer, it seems to me the the original `sed` method above is a much simpler way to go (see @Beta's answer). Use perl though. perl is one of the most portable languages around, and always trumps grep/sed/awk et. al. `echo '${one-line}' | perl -lpe 's/_NEWLINE_/\n/g'` maybe. (Or `perl -lpe 'BEGIN { $$/ = "_NEWLINE_" }'`—timtowtdi as the Perl folks say.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is GNU make, then do it all in make.

```
one-line := lib/alarms-1.2/priv/snmp_conf/agent.conf: lib/alarms/priv/snmp_conf/agent.conf_NEWLINE_lib/alarms-1.2/priv/snmp_conf/agent.conf.src: lib/alarms/priv/snmp_conf/agent.conf.src_NEWLINE_lib/alarms-1.2/priv/snmp_conf/community.conf: lib/alarms/priv/snmp_conf/community.conf

define \n


endef

many-lines := $(subst _NEWLINE_,${\n},${one-line})
```

Now `${many-lines}` has just what you want. Annoyingly, it's quite hard to use in shell lines. If you do this:

```
tgt:
    echo '${many-lines}'
```

make will invoke a *separate* shell for *each* line. The first shell invocation will get an un-paired `'` and exit with an error.

```
.ONESHELL:
tgt:
    echo '${many-lines}'
```

will work in an invasive sort of way. The proper fix is to ensure each line of `${many-lines}` has valid sh syntax. Some mouthfull like:

```
echolines = $(subst ${\n},'${\n}echo ',echo '${many-lines}')
.PHONY: aa
aa:
    $(call echolines,${many-lines})
```

Sheesh.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good start. I was thinking about something similar but didn't have patience to figure out where to put the echo's. Are you able to add echoing each line to a file, as this is the ultimate goal? I think in your approach each line should have the format: "echo 'target: file' >> test.txt" but I couldn't figure out where to add the ">> test.txt" part. To me it looks like there will be a problem with the last line, as it doesn't end with "\n" and can't be easily substituted. I mean it should still be possible with adding _NEWLINE_ at the end but is becoming even more messy.

Comment: Actually, I think I got `$echolines` wrong as echo always adds a newline (apart from `-c` in some `echo`s). Having slept on it, a better way is to turn `str1\nstr2\nstr3\n` into `{echo 'str1' && echo 'str2' && echo 'str3'}`. This is a single shell invocation, and will be quite happy with a single indirection (`$(call echolines2,${many-lines}) >$@`).

Comment: I am not sure what I may be doing wrong but something still doesn't work: `many-lines := echo '$(subst _NEWLINE_,' && echo ',${one-line})'` `echolines = $(subst ${\n},'${\n}echo ', ${many-lines})` `$(call echolines,${many-lines}) > test.txt` prints one line to the file and the other two to the standard output.

Comment: Properly read my previous comment. You want the shell command to look like `{ echo 'str1' && echo 'str2' && echo 'str3'; } >file'`. Notice those curlies. They cause the indirection to happen for all of the `echo`s.

Comment: AFAIK grouping commands in braces is a feature of the Bash shell, not the GNU make. So this won't work since the make uses sh by default, not Bash.

Comment: @Amiramix: AFAIK braces for command grouping are in standard _sh_, so you should be fine. (Brace expansion is not, but that is something else altogether!)

Answer (score 1):

Tried many different solutions, including defining `\n` as mentioned in this answer: [Add a newline in Makefile 'foreach' loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788276/add-a-newline-in-makefile-foreach-loop)

The real problem is inconsistent implementation of the `echo` command across platforms, and the fact that by default `make` invokes shell commands using `sh`, which itself is quite inflexible.

I found a better way thanks to this answer: ["echo -e" when called directly and when called via a shell-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591467/echo-e-when-called-directly-and-when-called-via-a-shell-script)

**The better way is to use `printf` instead of `echo`**

Construct the string with `\n` instead of `_NEWLINE_` to separate parts that go into separate lines in the output file:

```
some_string = lib/alarms-1.2/priv/snmp_conf/target_params.conf: lib/alarms/priv/snmp_conf/target_params.conf\nlib/alarms-1.2/priv/snmp_conf/community.conf: lib/alarms/priv/snmp_conf/community.conf\n
```

and then in the makefile print it simply as this:

```
@printf "$(some_string)" >> $(some_file)
```

Works on both, FreeBSD and Solaris.

Comment: This is fragile in the case where _some_string_ contains `%` characters.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I have no experience with Solaris or FreeBSD... here goes anyway.

In make, you can use $(patsubst pattern,replacement,text) to substitute a pattern.
try this...

```
FILENAMES := "lib/alarms-1.2/priv/snmp_conf/agent.conf: lib/alarms/priv/snmp_conf/agent.conf_NEWLINE_lib/alarms-1.2/priv/snmp_conf/agent.conf.src: lib/alarms/priv/snmp_conf/agent.conf.src_NEWLINE_lib/alarms-1.2/priv/snmp_conf/community.conf: lib/alarms/priv/snmp_conf/community.conf"

.PHONY: all

all:
    @echo $(patsubst _NEWLINE_,${\n},$(FILENAMES))
```

Comment: That doesn't work because _NEWLINE_ isn't white-space separated from other words. But thanks for trying.

Comment: BTW using subst instead of patsubst doesn't work either (because \n isn't properly substituted). I guess you didn't test your code?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, I think your first approach will work, if you just double the `$` to "escape" it:

```
sed 's|_NEWLINE_|\'$$'\n|g'
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. On Solaris it's outputting conf$nlib (replacing _NEWLINE_ with $n).